# Fatal error : Index out of range

Tags: arrays, swift

I m getting this error :fatal error: Index out of range  .I can't  get what i m doing wrong .What i'm trying to do is , access an array dictionary by using an integer index than  pass a string to get the value mapped to it .The sample works fine on playground but not excode why ? (The array dictionary is not empty) 
[image: I have run the same code on playground and it worked]   [image: the xcode error][image: the array is not empty]
 Here is my code

```
var CondoIndivi2 = [[String:AnyObject]]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    scrollView.contentSize.height = 1500


    print(CondoIndivi2)
    if let description_Condo = self.CondoIndivi2[0]["description"] as? String {

       print(description_Condo)

    }



}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 }
```

This is the view that sends data to CondoIndivi2

```
        import UIKit
        import  Alamofire
        import SwiftyJSON

       class SignleCondoTableViewController: UITableViewController {
@IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

var singleCondoData =  [[String:AnyObject]]()
var CondoIndivi = [[String:AnyObject]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between  presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
     }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int      {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
     }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return singleCondoData.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SignleTableTableViewCell


    if singleCondoData.count != 0 {


        let dict = singleCondoData[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary


        //cell.label1.text? = (dict["name"] as? String)!

        if let nullcheck = (dict["address"] as? String) {
            cell.label2.text? = nullcheck
        }

    }



    return cell
     }



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let dict = singleCondoData[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary


    if let unitNullCheck = (dict["mls_number"] as? String) {
        let item_id = unitNullCheck
        getCondoUnits(item_id)
        print(item_id)

        }



      }

      //get the individual condo id

func getCondoUnits(condo_id : String){


    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://android.goidx.com/search/?mls_number=" + String(condo_id)).validate().responseJSON { response in

        if let value  = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(value)

            if let resData = json.arrayObject {

                self.CondoIndivi = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]

                print(self.CondoIndivi)


            }

            if self.CondoIndivi.count > 0 {

                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }


         }

        }

        }



override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {


        switch identifier  {

        case "details" :


            let buildingdDetailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController


            buildingdDetailVC.CondoIndivi2  = self.CondoIndivi
         default:
            break
        }

          }

        }







/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
```

Comment: `self.CondoIndivi2` is initially empty. Do you ever put something in it?

Comment: i just edited the question . yeah i m send data to it using prepareforsegue

Comment: what do you think could be the probelm?

Comment: I guess your make a request in getCondoUnits, which is asynchronous.So you navigated to the destination ViewController before the download ended.You should make your request in your destination ViewController. Have a try:-)

Comment: have you connected your segue from cell to buildingDetailVC?

Comment: yeah the segue is there .I m sending the data based on the cell the  user pressed on the tableview.CondoIndivi2 which is in the detail view will get the data and display it using labels .So i dont know what's wrong with the logic

Answer (score 0):

As @James put in his comment, you're creating an empty array in your code:

```
var CondoIndivi2 = [[String:AnyObject]]()
```

And then you're trying to access indexing in the position 0:

```
if let description_Condo = self.CondoIndivi2[0]["description"] as? String {
   print(description_Condo)
}
```

And of course, you will have a runtime error of `Index of out Range` because your array it's empty, you always need to be sure before index an array that the index is greater than zero, less than equal to the size of the array and the array is not empty.

I hope this help you.

Comment: i just edited the question . yeah i m send data to it using prepareforsegue .The array is not empty

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `getCondoUnits(condo_id : String)` is an asynchronous block(`Alamofire.request`), the `CondoIndivi2` is received later than the viewDidLoad is executed. You should just pass `condo_id` to next viewController and do the request in it.